# Routing and OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, nat

Need help configuring the route to internal LAN.

I need to access my internal network when connected to my OpenVPN Router. I can access Internal LAN1, which is directly connected to OpenVPN Router but I can't access the LAN2, which is connected to Router2. How can accomplish this.

Here is the config:

Internet ==>[x.x.x.x]OpenVPN Router[192.168.1.1]===>[192.168.1.2]LAN Router2===>192.168.0.1

I can VPN into 192.168.1.x network fine but I can't connect to 192.168.0.x network. Router2 is TPLInk.

Can someone define the routing that I need to add to internal Router2 and the external )openVPN Router"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In a network of this size, routes correspond almost directly to descriptions in English. For example:

1. *OpenVPN_router* needs to reach 192.168.0.x, which is `192.168.0.0/24` in CIDR notation
2. *OpenVPN_router* can reach `192.168.0.0/24` by going through *LAN_router2*
3. From *OpenVPN_router*'s perspective, *LAN_router2* is `192.168.1.2`
4. Therefore, the route that *OpenVPN_router* needs is `192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2`.

   - various GUIs: destination = `192.168.0.0/24`, gateway = `192.168.1.2`
   - Linux CLI: `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2`
   - FreeBSD CLI: `route add 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.1.2`
   - (How to configure it permanently varies greatly across distros.)

In the opposite direction:

1. *LAN_router2* needs to reach your VPN subnet, which you forgot to mention in the question...
2. *LAN_router2* can reach that subnet by going through *OpenVPN_router*
3. And so on.